# aws elastic load balancer and limits

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any limit for the number of vpc to be attached to an elastic load balancer in aws. I have created an ELB with one VPC , I wanted to know , whether I can have multiple vpc on the same load balancer?

Comment: Can you explain what's the use case you are trying to solve? Load Blancer can be associated with only one VPC...

Comment: I was asking whether we can implement the same elb in different vpcs in a region.

Comment: Elb can be associated with one vpc only. But it targets can be in different vpc if you have peered vpcs.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) you must specify exactly one VPC. In this VPC you can select one subnet per Availability Zone (AZ).

These settings are needed to assign an IP address to the ELB. When you configure one one subnet then the ELB hat only one IP in this subnet. It is recommended to assign at least two subnets (in different AZs) to the ELB. This way any outage in one AZ does not affect the ELB.

Remember that this configuration is only for input data. Therefore, we handle the question how to connect to the ELB. Configuring output, e.g. where to forward the data by ELB, is another topic.